# How many times a string occurs in another string (textbox) VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox, count, find

How can I get how many times a string occurs in a textbox?

I thought the find function would return the number of times found but it seems to return the location of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Regex.Matches(textBox1.Text, Regex.Escape(inputString)).Count`

Comment: id be interested to know the performance of this, but +1 for clear simple code.

Comment: `Import System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Regex provides best performance for simple searches, especially if you use the `Compiled` flag and precreate the regex object. But I never benchmarked this.

Comment: This will not work as expected if `inputString` contains special characters.  You need to call `Regex.Escape`.

Comment: @Jonathan: If you use this, change it to `Regex.Matches(textBox1.Text, Regex.Escape(inputString)).Count`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Split`, like this:

```
(" " + textBox1.Text + " ").Split(New String() { inputString }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Alternatively, you can keep calling `IndexOf` with the startIndex equal to the previous call's return value + 1 until it returns -1.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is about twice as slow as regex, tested and benchmarked. Code at http://pastebin.com/m52d69edc

Comment: Even without precompiling the regex, and with using Regex.Escape on each call, the regex is still twice as fast as the Split way, plus you can divine additional information from the regex such as where the matches are located in the original string.

Comment: I must say that that's quite surprising.

Comment: Few things can beat the performance of a well-implemented regular expression search engine, provided the pattern and the text are not known or indexed in advance.

Comment: Actually, a loop using instr is about 30% faster than regex in this case.

Comment: What if you need to search one of two words? :-)